# Elasticsearch query over nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

trying to query a particular index with nested field according to the following

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "search_field": [
                    "search_key"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "nested": {
          "path": "defined_path",   //defined path is mapped nested
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "defined_path.some_field"
                    }
                  }
                ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but this tends to give out some error and the syntax(query_parsing_exception) shows to be wrong but doesn't seem the case.
what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing to encapsulate the 2nd must condition inside `{}`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "search_field": [
                    "search_key"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "defined_path",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "defined_path.some_field"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```